# Como a conexão do pymongo é estabelecida?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Estou construindo um programa que checa um banco de dados a cada minuto e, caso algumas condições forem atendidas, o programa faz diversas requisições via APIs e conversa com o MongoDB para tratar e salvar os dados. É muito importante que eu não perca nenhum dado quando quando o programa for rodar continuamente.

Para (tentar) evitar isso, eu criei uma função tenta múltiplas vezes a conexão com a internet. A função é muito maior, mas para terem uma ideia:

```
def try_connection(func, *args, **kwargs):
    for _ in range(10):
        try:
            r = func(*args, **kwargs)

        #Diversos outros excepts

        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f'Erro inesperado: {e.__class__}, {e}', exc_info=True)
            sleep(30)
```

Eu estava passando minhas `queries` ao MongoDB dentro da função `try_connection`. Algo como:

```
alarms = try_connection(collection.find)
alarms = try_connection(alarms.sort, 'alarmID', -1)
```

No entanto, nos testes que eu realizei (numa rede sem VPN fechada ao banco, inviabilizando meu acesso) via console, os problemas de conexão não acontecem no momento da `query`, ou seja, quando o `cursor` é formado, mas quando vou iterar sobre ele.

```
>>> user_mongo = urllib.parse.quote_plus(config.user_mongo)
>>> pass_mongo = urllib.parse.quote_plus(config.pass_mongo)
>>> c = try_connection(pymongo.MongoClient, 
        f'mongodb://{user_mongo}:{pass_mongo}@10.0.0.0:27017/{db_name}')
>>> db = c[db_name]
>>> collection = db[collection_name]
>>> alarms = try_connection(collection.find)
>>> alarms = try_connection(alarms.sort, 'alarmID', -1)
>>> print(alarms)
<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x034EDCF0>
>>> for alarm in alarms:
...     print(alarm)
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Murilo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 611, in __getitem__
    for doc in clone:
  File "C:\Users\Murilo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 1225, in next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
  File "C:\Users\Murilo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymongo\cursor.py", line 1117, in _refresh
    self.__session = self.__collection.database.client._ensure_session()
  File "C:\Users\Murilo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1598, in _ensure_session
    return self.__start_session(True, causal_consistency=False)
  File "C:\Users\Murilo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1551, in __start_session
    server_session = self._get_server_session()
  File "C:\Users\Murilo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymongo\mongo_client.py", line 1584, in _get_server_session
    return self._topology.get_server_session()
  File "C:\Users\Murilo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 429, in get_server_session
    None)
  File "C:\Users\Murilo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pymongo\topology.py", line 200, in _select_servers_loop
    self._error_message(selector))
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: 10.0.0.0:27017: timed out
```

Isso me fez pensar que o `cursor` apenas aponta para os locais onde os dados da `query` estão localizados (ao invés de armazenar os dados, como eu pensava. Eu pensava que esse suposto armazenamento era o motivo de termos que usar um `rewind()` para acessar o `cursor` após uma iteração). Tentei procurar informações nos documentos oficiais, mas não achei nenhuma resposta satisfatória.

Então, **como a conexão é estabelecida**? Para tentar evitar que eu perca algum dado eu **sempre devo chamar `try_connection` quando for iterar sobre os `cursores` ao invés de chamar na hora das `queries`**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [documentação](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-cursor) define um cursor como:

> A pointer to the result set of a query. Clients can iterate through a
>   cursor to retrieve results.

Ou seja, o cursor apenas aponta para o resultado, ao invés de armazená-lo. Para contornar meu problema eu deveria encapsular minhas iterações em uma função e chamar `try_connection` sempre que for executá-la.

No entanto, achei melhor criar mais um método dentro da minha classe `Mongo` e chamá-lo antes de realizar uma iteração.

```
class Mongo:
    def __init__(self, db):
        self.db = db

...
...
...

    def check_connection(self):
        try_connection(self.db.client.admin.command, 'ismaster')
```

`c.admin.command('ismaster')` é o comando indicado pela [documentação](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html) do pymongo para checar se uma conexão foi estabelecida. (`c == db.client`)

No meu código principal, eu faço.

```
mongo = Mongo(db)

...
...
...

ids = clients.find(
                    {
                    }, 
                    {
                        'serviceID': 1, 
                        'wrongSeverity': 1, 
                        '_id': 0
                    }
                )
mongo.check_connection()
ids = [id['serviceID'] for id in ids if not id['wrongSeverity']]
```